# C++ Функция уже имеет тип реализации

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пытаюсь разобраться с многофайловыми проектами,но получаю 3 непонятных ошибки, причины появления которых я найти не смог. Подскажите, где ошибки?

Ошибка  C2660   first: функция не принимает 2 аргументов
Ошибка  C2084   функция "float *first(void)" уже имеет текст реализации

Ошибка  C2084   функция "void second(int *,float *)" уже имеет текст реализации

Main файл

```
   #include "pch.h"
     int first(int *x, int *y)
{
    static  double var1; // переобьявление переменной внутри функции
    float * result = first();// вызвал доп.файл из основного

    return 0;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    int var1 = 15;
    int* pvar1;
    pvar1 = &var1;
    int result = first(pvar1, pvar1);



    return 0;

}
```

Source1

```
#include "pch.h"


 extern int* x = 0;


 float* first(void) // переобьявил функцию в доп.файле
{

    float *y = 0;

    second(x,y); // передал глобальную переменную как параметр функции
    return 0;
}
```

Source 2

```
#include "pch.h"



void second(int * one, float *two)
{
    double result2 = (*one) * (*two);
    int * px;
    *px = 1;
    int func = first(px, px);

}
```

pch.h

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


extern float var2;
float * first(void);
int first(int *, int *);
void second(int*, float *);
// TODO: add headers that you want to pre-compile here

#endif //PCH_H
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что это код С

Comment: Это задумывалось как код С++,но до этого я писал только на С и С#,так что все возможно

Comment: @Alexey он к тому, что файлы у Вас *.c или *.cpp?

Comment: Судя по всему это в студии, а там кажется убрали шаблон *.с, есть только *.срр из коробки.